# Realizar una acción automática sobre JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Mi pregunta es como  puedo realizar una acción automática sobre mi JFrame? Quiero que al ejecutar mi proyecto se dispare una acción automática la cual dispararía un determinado código, por ej: Tengo el siguiente código

```
private void ocultarJFrame() {
        parent.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent arg0) {
                if (arg0.getNewState() == JFrame.ICONIFIED) {
                    parent.dispose();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

La acción que busco es que realice un clic automático en mi JFrame que lo minimice sin que el usuario no lo note, o sea el código que tengo, nose si me explico. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Segun leo tu comentario creo que esto es lo que necesitas: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html  primero leelo y despues ven con una pregunta mas concreta.

Comment: Si me permites el comentario creo que eso no le servirá de mucho, salvo que quiera hacer una aplicación de ese tipo (que no es el caso).

Comment: Le di una respuesta y esto fue lo que me respondio "Ya lo e intentado pero no me resulta, lo inicio minimizado pero yo necesito que se oculte al ejecutar, porque estoy haciendo una aplicación que corra en segundo plano en la barra de notificaciones se entiende? "

Comment: Lo resolví de la siguiente manera, **Hice un proyecto totalmente de cero con una clase `Main` la cual no tenia mi proyecto original, Comencé basando todo mi proyecto en un JFrame y lo que yo quería era hacer una aplicación en segundo plano la cual correría en la barra de notificaciones del SO a si que presindi del JFrame, llame a mi clase madre `Notificacion`la cual llama a las demás clases, hace toda la lógica del sistema y guala! La magia se hizo.. Muchas gracias por su ayuda, se agradece de verdad.**

Answer (score 0):

Añade el siguiente código en el constructor de tu JFrame, justo debajo de la llamada a **initComponents()**:

```
public JPanelZoom() {
    initComponents();

    // Minimizar JFrame
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
}
```

Comment: Lo resolví de la siguiente manera, **Hice un proyecto totalmente de cero con una clase `Main` la cual no tenia mi proyecto original, Comencé basando todo mi proyecto en un JFrame y lo que yo queria era hacer una aplicación en segundo plano la cual correría en la barra de notificaciones del SO a si que presindi del JFrame, llame a mi clase madre `Notificacion`la cual llama a las demás clases, hace toda la lógica del sistema y guala! La magia se hizo.. Muchas gracias por su ayuda, se agradece.**